# Security of localhost connection

Tags: php, mysql, security, encryption

I realise that this may seem an odd question (and I apologise for asking what almost answers itself) however I was concerned after reading responses to other questions:

I have a php script which stores data in a localhost MYSQL database.  Some of that information is sensitive and is encrypted using the MYSQL AES encryption function.

I read that MYSQL does not encrypt the data in its connections.  This was mentioned in two recent replies that dealt with localhost connections, hence my concern.

I have always thought that as the data was being passed internally in the same computer, the risk of interception was zero.  Is this not the case, then?  should I be encrypting in PHP before storing the data?

I am using mysqli_*

Connection to the server is via SSL.

I currently use a shared virtual server though once development is complete I plan to move to a dedicated machine.

Please would an expert either put my mind at rest or tell me how I should be doing this.

Comment: You say `I read that MYSQL does not encrypt the data in its connections.` but you say also `Connection to the server is via SSL.` If you are using `SSL` you should be fine.

Comment: if the connection between the web server and the database server is over ssl then you are good.

Comment: I'd say that if an attacker is already inside your machine and in a position to intercept unencrypted database traffic, he could probably intercept anything else he wants to as well. As such, worrying about this may be somewhat pointless. Having said that, try http://security.stackexchange.com for some real professional opinions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have guessed, it is kind of pointless to use SSL for local connections. SSL's main purpose is to encrypt the channel so as to prevent man-in-the-middle-like attacks. But there can be no man in the middle in case of local connection. In you setup, I would recommend a connection through a [local socket](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connecting.html#option_general_socket), and bypass the TCP layer altogether.

Now back to the question.

> Should I be encrypting in PHP before storing the data?

No, if the database is on the same machine as the one that executes the script.

No, if the database is remote, and if the link is trusted (either you trust the link *per se*, or the link is secured eg. with SSL).

Yes, in all other situations.

In the latter case (untrusted link to a remote database), `AES_ENCRYPT()` is not suitable. The encryption/decryption process is done by MySQL. The data transits unencrypted between PHP and MySQL. Also, as one must pass an encryption key to MySQL's `AES_ENCRYPT()` and `AES_DECRYPT()`, this key will typically be sent unencrypted along with the rest of the SQL query.

Comment: Thank you.  The SSL connection is just between site users and the server, not internally.  I am suitably reassured!

Comment: "Connect to the localhost" and you'll fine, you mean?